# Put each variadic template argument into container

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, variadic-templates

Is there a way in modern C++ to put each of the variadic template arguments into a container within a `std::tuple`? For example:

```
template<class ... T>
class MyClass {
private:
std::tuple<T...> myTuple;
};

int main() {
MyClass<int, char, float> test; //inner class stores an std::tuple<int, char, float>
//is there a way to make the inner class store std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<char>, std::vector<float>>
return 0;
}
```

Tuples do not have to be used, as long as I get a class with an end result of each variadic template argument being stored in a container like a `std::vector`.

Comment: Dou you mean `private: std::tuple<std::vector<T>...> myTuple;` ?

Comment: @max66 hmm I'll try that out...

Comment: @max66 It looks like that worked. I'm trying to upvote you / select you for best answer, sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Well, max66 has not yet posted an answer, so you can't upvote/accept it yet :) If no one posts an answer after a reasonable period, you can go ahead and answer the question yourself, but make sure to credit the user for their comment that helped you solve the problem.

Comment: @cigien Okay will do, thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a way to make the inner class store `std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<char>, std::vector<float>`

You have simply to unpack the `T` variadic list inside `std::tuple<std::vector<...>>`.

I mean

```
template<class ... T>
class MyClass {
   private:
      std::tuple<std::vector<T>...> myTuple;
}; // ...........^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```